# Entity Framework - Duplicate Existing Classes, Code First?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to think of a way to store actual templates of ticket items in my Entity Framework MVC project. The thing is, I've already done a Code First migration process in the past. What I need to do is create logic in my code to allow someone to save time creating a ticket by using pre-loaded data from a template. My current inheritance model uses an abstract class (MasterTicket) which is used as the parent since to me there can be multiple categories (a Google Calendar based task, "Appointment Task" and a purely internal task, "General Task"). Here's my parent abstract class:

```
[Table("Ticket")]
[ModelBinder(typeof(MasterTicketBinder))]
public abstract class MasterTicket
{
    [Key]
    public Guid id{ get; set; }
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ART { get; set; }
    public DateTime openTime{ get; set; }
    public DateTime? closeTime { get; set; }
    private bool active = true;
    public bool Active{ get => active; set => active = value; }
    public string summary{ get; set; }
    public string description{ get; set; }
    public DateTime updateTime{ get; set; }
    //TODO: Create foreign key relationship to user model
    public Guid userUpdateId{ get; set; }
    //TODO: Create foreign key relationship for tickets from other systems
    public Guid externalAppId{ get; set; }
    //TODO: Create foreign key relationship to user model
    public Guid userOpenId{ get; set; }
    public Guid? userCloseId { get; set; }
    public Guid userOwnerId{ get; set; }
    private int timesUpdated = 0;
    public int TimesUpdated { get => timesUpdated; set => timesUpdated = value; }
    public DateTime expectedCompletionTime{ get; set; }
    public DateTime actualCompletionTime{ get; set; }
    public List<MasterTicketItem> masterTicketItems{ get; set; }
    

    public MasterTicket()
    {

    }
}
```

An here's an example of the concrete Google Calendar-based "Appointment Task" child:

```
[Table("AppointmentTickets")]
public class ApptTaskTicket : MasterTicket
{
    public DateTime currentApptTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime? endApptTime { get; set; }
    public bool allDay { get; set; }
    public string customerName { get; set; }
    //TODO: Create foreign relationship
    public Guid subjectPrsnlId { get; set; }
    public string gCalEventId { get; set; }
    public string customerPhone { get; set; }
    public string customerEmail { get; set; }
    public string preferredContactMethod { get; set; }
    public List<ApptConfirmItem> apptConfirmItems { get; set; }
}
```

I know I can easily create a column for the MasterTicket class to indicate that it's a template, but to me I feel it's cleaner to have a separate "Template Table" if you will that will store pre-existing values that can be filled in with a form. In this case, I think I would WANT to create a duplicate class that would store said templates so that there are only several rows. What would be the best way to do this with Code First? Does someone feel I should take a different approach? Maybe DB First is a better way to go?

In case it matters, here's my DBContext for the Tickets:

```
// Code-Based Configuration and Dependency resolution  
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]
public class TicketDB : DbContext
{

    public TicketDB(): base("AffirmativeServiceSystem.Properties.Settings.AffirmTaskManager")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<MasterTicket> tickets { get; set; }
    

    public DbSet<MasterTicketItem> ticketItems { get; set; }
    

}
```

Comment: Your entire question is about how to want to store "pre-loaded data" in a _"separate "Template Table" if you will that will store pre-existing values that can be filled in with a form"_, but that's the only thing you explain about it. Pre-existing values for _what_? And why? What would these values look like, when will you query them, how often and how will you alter them, and so on?

Comment: I want a user to be able to store pre-existing values in these data objects in a separate template store. The goal is to be able to save them time filling in values when they are using the form to create said item by using a stored template. Example: They create a "Trash Task" template. When they select it, the summary and description for the Master Ticket is already there. Summary: "Take out trash." Description: "Please take the trash out to the back end dumpster."

Comment: The main Ticket table currently just stores instances of tasks in a row by row fashion.

Comment: I really think this just calls for an EAV table with the columns TicketType, TemplateName, FIeldName, DefaultValue. You definitely don't want to create a template table for each ticket type table, and you _probably_ also don't want a separate table per ticket type. So your question boils down to database design, and that's a very broad subject. A lot of constraints and usages are missing from your question, try and describe in more detail what you actually want to do.

Comment: @CodeCaster that may be right.Do you have a link or example of an implementation of this in Entity Framework? Not that I'm not willing to dig.

Comment: @CodeCaster been doing more digging, I definitely think you're right. Would the FieldName/DefaultValue columns be best stored in a List or collection of some sort? I would think the answer is yes?